bcrypt hashing password nodejs
i keep getting this error "Invalid password" even if the password and email are correct which makes no sense pls help me to solve this problem i think that i am comparing a hashed password and a plain text password but i dont know how to solve it
app.post('/login0', (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?";
    const values = [email];

    db.query(sql, values, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Database error: ", err);
            return res.status(500).json({ message: "Login failed: Database error" });
        }
        
        if (result.length > 0) {
            const storedPassword = result[0].password;
            if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, storedPassword)) {
                console.log("Password match, login successful");
                return res.status(200).json({ message: "Login successful", user: result[0] });
            } else {
                console.log("Invalid password");
                return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid password" });
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Account not found");
            return res.status(401).json({ message: "Account not found" });
        }
    });
});


the passwords are stored hashed in the data base
app.post('/add_user', (req, res) => {
console.log("Post request on /add_user");

const { name, lastname, email, password, address, number } = req.body;

bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error generating salt:', err);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
        return;
    }

    bcrypt.hash(password, salt, (err, hashedPassword) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error hashing password:', err);
            res.status(500).send('Server error');
            return;
        }

        const sql = "INSERT INTO user (name, lastname, email, password, address, number) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        const values = [name, lastname, email, hashedPassword, address, number];

        db.query(sql, values, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error inserting into database:', err);
                res.status(500).send('Server error');
                return;
            }
            console.log("User added successfully");
            res.status(200).send('User added successfully');
        });
    });
});

});

i did share it the passwords are stored after being hased

I had the same problem with bcrypt. I was using that method:
   public async signIn(email: string, pass: string): Promise<{ access_token: string }> {
        this.logger.log(`email and password from controller signIn(): ${email} - ${pass}`)
      
        try {
          const { user, found } = await this.usersService.findOneByEmail(email);
          if(!found || !user) throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid credentials');
      
          this.logger.log(`Hash password stored: ${user.password}`);
          this.logger.log(`Password provided: ${pass}`);
      
const isPasswordMatching = await bcrypt.compare(pass, user.password);
      this.logger.log(Resultado da comparação da senha: ${isPasswordMatching});
if (!isPasswordMatching) throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid credentials')
        
          const payload: AccessTokenPayload = {
            sub: user.id,
            email: user.email,
          };
      
          const accessToken = await this.jwtService.signAsync(payload, {
            secret: this.configService.get<string>('JWT_SECRET'),
            expiresIn: this.configService.get<string>('EXPIRES_IN')
          });
      
          return { access_token: accessToken };
      
        } catch(error) {
          this.logger.error(`Erro no método signIn()`, error.message);
          throw error;
        }
      }

And the error was that the password that I was providing was invalid. I'm using bycrpt version 5.1.1 and the database is PostgreSQL.
Then, I tried to use the callback version of compare(), and changed the method to use this:
  bcrypt.compare(pass, user.password, (err) => {
    console.log("erro: ", err.message);
  });

With that modification everything works! I don't why, but maybe this can resolve your issue.
